# Python Hangman Replacing Letters

Tags: python

Basically, this is my code for hangman game so far. I need some help please. So first of all if someone could revise my code by adding the things if possible. 1) I don't know how to replace the letters with the underscores. So every time when the user inputs the correct letter, it should replace the correct underscore/s. 2) I don't know how to cut lives if the person guesses the incorrect letter. **Note: I have the actual word printed for testing which I will remove later on.**

```
import time
import random

#words

simpWords = ['triskaidekaphobia', 'spaghettification', 'sesquipedalian', 'floccinaucinihilipilification', 'deipnosophist']
medWords = ['erubescent', 'entomophogy', 'noctambulist', 'parapente', 'umbriferous']
hardWords = ['cat', 'house', 'degust', 'glaikit', 'otalgia']

simpWordsR = random.choice(simpWords)
medWordsR = random.choice(medWords)
hardWordsR = random.choice(hardWords)


#welcome the user

name = input("What is your name?")
print ("Hello! " + name + ". Time to play Hangman")

#wait for 1 second
time.sleep(1)

print ("")

correctLetters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'

#picking levels

gameMode = input('Choose a level - Easy (10 Guesses), Medium (8 Guesses) or Hard (7 Guesses)')
if gameMode == str('easy'):
  numberOfGuesses1 = 11
  print ('')
  print (list(simpWordsR))
  blanks = '_ ' * len(simpWordsR)
  correctLetters = ''
  for i in range(len(simpWordsR)): # replace blanks with correctly guessed letters
    if simpWordsR[i] in correctLetters:
      blanks = blanks[:i] + simpWordsR[i] + blanks[i+1:]
  print (blanks)

elif gameMode == str('medium'):
  numberOfGuesses2 = 8
  print ('')
  print (list(medWordsR))
  blanks = '_ ' * len(medWordsR)
  correctLetters = ''
  for i in range(len(medWordsR)): # replace blanks with correctly guessed letters
    if medWordsR[i] in correctLetters:
      blanks = blanks[:i] + medWordsR[i] + blanks[i+1:]
  print (blanks)

elif gameMode == str('hard'):
  numberOfGuesses3 = 7
  print ('')
  print (list(hardWordsR))
  blanks = '_ ' * len(hardWordsR)
  correctLetters = ''
  for i in range(len(hardWordsR)): # replace blanks with correctly guessed letters
    if hardWordsR[i] in correctLetters:
      blanks = blanks[:i] + hardWordsR[i] + blanks[i+1:]
  print (blanks)

time.sleep(1)

print ("")

numberOfGuesses1 -= 1
print (numberOfGuesses1)

while numberOfGuesses1 == 10:
  guess = input("Guess a Character!")

  if (guess in simpWordsR):
   print ("Well Done! You Guessed it right!")

  else:
    print ("The letter is not in the word. Try Again!")


if numberOfGuesses1 == 0:
  print ("Game Finished. Maybe Try Again y/n.")
```

Thank you very much for all the help. I am actually a beginner in python programming. I have tried out other examples but it just doesn't work with my code for some reason and I did change the variables.

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: Welcome to SO. Do not post pics of code or links to code. [edit] your question. Copy and paste the code into your question. Visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: I have posted it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the comments in the code:

```
import time
import random

#words

simpWords = ['triskaidekaphobia', 'spaghettification', 'sesquipedalian', 'floccinaucinihilipilification', 'deipnosophist']
medWords = ['erubescent', 'entomophogy', 'noctambulist', 'parapente', 'umbriferous']
hardWords = ['cat', 'house', 'degust', 'glaikit', 'otalgia']

# Just use one word, which will be set after user selects difficulty
#simpWordsR = random.choice(simpWords)
#medWordsR = random.choice(medWords)
#hardWordsR = random.choice(hardWords)


#welcome the user

name = input("What is your name?")
print ("Hello! " + name + ". Time to play Hangman")

#wait for 1 second
time.sleep(1)

print ("")

# Removed uppercase. We will only use lower case
alphabet = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz'

#picking levels

gameMode = input('Choose a level - Easy (10 Guesses), Medium (8 Guesses) or Hard (7 Guesses)').lower()
if gameMode == 'easy':
    numberOfGuesses = 11
    theWord = random.choice(simpWords)
    # Not sure what this is for....deleted
    #correctLetters = ''
    #for i in range(len(simpWordsR)): # replace blanks with correctly guessed letters
    #  if simpWordsR[i] in correctLetters:
    #    blanks = blanks[:i] + simpWordsR[i] + blanks[i+1:]
    #print (blanks)

elif gameMode == 'medium':
    numberOfGuesses = 8
    theWord = random.choice(medWords)

else:
    numberOfGuesses = 7
    theWord = random.choice(hardWords)

print(gameMode)
print(theWord)  # For debugging purposes

# Since python strings are immutable, use a list
blanks = ['_'] * len(theWord)

# Need to keep a list of already guessed letters
used_letters = []

time.sleep(1)

print ("")

# Move this to the loop
#numberOfGuesses1 -= 1
#print (numberOfGuesses1)

#while numberOfGuesses1 == 10:
while numberOfGuesses > 0:
    print (numberOfGuesses)
    print (' '.join(blanks))

    # get user input and convert to lower case
    guess = input("Guess a Character!").lower()

    # Make sure it's a letter
    if not guess in alphabet:
        print("Enter a letter...")
    # Make sure not already guessed
    elif guess in used_letters:
        print("Already guessed that....")
    # Valid guess. Check it
    else:
        used_letters.append(guess)
        if (guess in theWord):
            print ("Well Done! You Guessed it right!")
            # Loop through and replace
            for x in range(0, len(theWord)):
                if theWord[x] == guess:
                    # Note: this works since theWord and blanks have the same length
                    blanks[x] = guess
            # Check for success
            if not '_' in blanks:
                print("You win")
                # End the loop
                break
        else:
            print ("The letter is not in the word. Try Again!")
            # Only decrement if incorrect
            numberOfGuesses -= 1

print ("Game Finished. Maybe Try Again y/n.")
```

Comment: `numberOfGuesses` should only be decremented on an incorrect guess. This means it cannot be used as the sole loop condition.

Comment: @Mark. Possibly. It's up to the game designer.

Comment: From OP: "I don't know how to cut lives if the person guesses the incorrect letter."

Comment: @Mark Ok. Updated.

Comment: thank you sooooo much for fixing the code! that was a great help!